# É possível deletar o "C:", usando Directory.Delete()?

Tags: c#, .net, diretório

Utilizando `Directory.Delete("C:", true)` deleta a partição? Ou apenas é bloqueado e não executa?

Comment: Já tentou testar? talvez usando o método [`Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390432(v=vs.85).aspx) da API [`Win32_Volume`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394515(v=vs.85).aspx) possa ajudar em algo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Directory.Delete()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.delete?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_IO_Directory_Delete_System_String_System_Boolean_) é feito para deletar arquivos e pastas. Ele não pode apagar uma partição que está em uma camada inferior ao que está usando.

Ele tentará apagar todas as pastas desta partição, mas dependerá de permissões. Se estiver rodando a aplicação com privilégio de administrador vai causar um belo estrago. Mesmo assim não apagará tudo. Outros problemas podem impedir o apagamento, conforme mostra a documentação.

Qualquer tentativa dependerá de permissão.

Não há tratamento especial para nenhuma situação.

Se quiser entender os detalhes, pode [acompanhar o código fonte dele](https://source.dot.net/#System.IO.FileSystem/System/IO/Directory.cs,b3ad5f0ba800bb28) (tem que ir seguindo os *links*). Em algum momento ele delega para o sistema operacional.

Comment: Isso vale para quando a participação não é a mesma do sistema operacional? Pergunto isso porque nem sempre o sistema operacional é instalado no C:

Comment: @GOKUSSJGod isso não faz muito sentido.

Comment: E se ele for invocado em `D://`... :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não muda nada, vou repetir: Não há tratamento especial para nenhuma situação. Qualquer tentativa dependerá de permissão.

Comment: +1 Muito bom o seu comentário!